# Prove that if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $AB=AC$ implies that $B=C$, then $A$ is invertable.

Tags: matrices

I'm horribly stuck on this question. I know if $A$ is invertable, $(A)(A^{-1})=I$ but that isn't helpful since I'm trying to prove $A$ is invertable.

Any ideas?

Comment: if A is not invertible, is there a non-zero matrix B such that AB=0 ?

Comment: Assume for contradiction that $A$ is not invertible.  What do you know about solutions to $Ax=b $?  Can you produce $B\neq C $ such that $AB=AC $?

Comment: The title isn't supposed to replace the first line of your question. Add quantifiers to the statement, otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @hardmath i have to assume B=C. All I've learned about Ax=b is that if A is invertible then "the system of equations Ax=b is consistent with a unique solution for all b"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argue by contradiction. If $A$ is not invertible then there exists $\vec{v}\ne \vec{0}$ such that $A\vec{v}=\vec{0}.$ Now consider $B=(\vec{v},\cdots, \vec{v})$ and $C=0_{n\times n}.$ Obviously,

$$AB=0_{n\times n}=AC.$$

This gives us a contradiction, since $B\ne C$.

Comment: In the question, I have to assume B=C.

Comment: No. If you assume $B=C$ then obviously $AB=AC,$ for any $A,$ invertible or not. So, $B=C$ is not the hypothesis but the thesis.

Comment: I think I follow, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

step 1)  Prove that $A$ is invertible iff $AX=0 \iff X=0$

step 2) Note $AB=AC \iff A(B-C)=0$

Edit after comment:

For 1) : if $\exists B$ s.t. $BA=I$ than 
$$AX=0 \Rightarrow BAX=B0 \Rightarrow IB=0 \Rightarrow B=0$$
Contaddiction.

In other words: if $A$ is a zero divisor than it is not invertible.

Comment: If I could prove A is invertible I would have solved the question. I might be misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: @James: I've edit and better formulate the answer.